# Screen Flickering When Charging

Tags: nvidia, graphics, kubuntu, kde, screen

I found that my notebook has screen flickering issue when it is charging at battery level approximately lower than 90%. Strangely, when the battery is above 90%, everything is fine. I have attached a video clip below illustrating the seriousness of the flickering.

[Video Clip Showing the Screen Flickering](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CGlbWVswL70rdl1SRpH75Yi8sgjRykaD/view?usp=sharing)

There are not many similar cases I could find from the Internet. I tried to tweak some setting in Compositor setting, such as the choice of "Tearing Prevention" but it didn't work. Currently, I have no clue where the problem is (whether it lies on graphical card, battery mode, or something else). Could anyone give me a pointer or suggestion on how I can diagnose the problem?

**Spec**

- OS Version: Ubuntu 18.04
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.12.9
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.44.0
- Kernel Version: 5.0.13-050013-generic
- Notebook Model: Lenovo Legion Y740
- Model Type: 006FHH (81UH006FHH)

**Compositor Setting**

- Rendering Backend: OpenGL 3.1
- Tearng Prevention: Automatic

**Remark**
In fact, there is another condition when the screen flickers. That's when I am training my deep learning model and charging. To test if it is an OS-specific issue, I ran the same model training script in Windows and Ubuntu respectively, only Ubuntu has this issue. The same applies to the condition where screen flickering occurs when charging at battery level lower than 90%.

Comment: It can be a hardware problem. Can you try with another OS (for example live Ubuntu 19.10)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I added a few details about the screen flickering. It seems to me it is more likely to be an OS specific issue. Anyway, I will give it a try on Ubuntu 19.10 if other attempts failed. (After all, it would cost me a while to reinstall OS and install everything needed again)

Comment: @alexwh There are seven (7) different Legion Y740 models; which do you have? Please flip it over and find the serial number sticker, then go to Lenovo's website https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/legion-series/legion-y740-17irh?linkTrack=&searchType=3&keyWordSearch=Legion%20Y740-17IRH%20Laptop%20(Lenovo)  and enter that number to find which you have. Then, please update your question with that info by clicking [edit] above. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, use [edit].

Comment: Ok! I have updated the model type in main post.